# How to convert Generic List<anonymous type > to Generic List <Classname>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database, where the CPU usage is inserted for every 'n' seconds and my task is to get the latest CPU entry from the database. I would like to display the latest CPU entry from the database tat belongs to the particular server , and I would like to save the result into a generic list.

what I have tried,

```
    string match = "ServerX"

    List<UsageCPU> cpus = (from a in db.UsageCPUs
                          where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
                          group a by a.ServerID into b
                          orderby b.Key
                          select new { ServerID = b.Key, 
                          Usage = b.FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

and I would like to loop through the result `cpus` to perform further other steps.

but I get the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<FNC_RAQIT_HM_UI.UsageCPU>'.

EDIT

[image]
**UPDATE**
The following query from Satpal worked for me.. but using `var`

```
   var cpus = (from a in db.UsageCPUs
                    where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
                    group a by a.ServerID into b
                    orderby b.Key
                    select new
                    {
                        ServerID = b.Key,
                        Usage = b.FirstOrDefault().Usage
                    }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in cpus)
        {
           if(bla bla..)
        }
```

kindly help !!

Comment: pls give reasons for down vote, so that I can reconstruct my question. Thanks !

Comment: try `Usage = b.First().Usage `

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<s>*Use*</s>

```
List<UsageCPU> cpus = (from a in db.UsageCPUs
                      where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
                      group a by a.ServerID into b
                      orderby b.Key
                      select new UsageCPU  //Added UsageCPU  
                      { 
                          ServerID = b.Key, 
                          Usage = b.FirstOrDefault().Usage 
                      }).ToList();
```

*Update as per error*

> The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

```
List<UsageCPU> cpus = (from a in db.UsageCPUs
                      where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
                      group a by a.ServerID into b
                      orderby b.Key
                      select new 
                      { 
                          ServerID = b.Key, 
                          Usage = b.FirstOrDefault().Usage
                      })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new UsageCPU  
                    {
                       ServerID ,
                       Usage            
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

try to select a not new
when you select new you get anonymous type which can't be  casted to `UsageCPU` type

```
 (from a in db.UsageCPUs
 where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
 group a by a.ServerID into b
 orderby b.Key
 select a)
```

or use var and then loop through the results

```
var cpus = (from a in db.UsageCPUs
                      where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
                      group a by a.ServerID into b
                      orderby b.Key
                      select new { ServerID = b.Key, 
                      Usage = b.FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

Comment: u mean, loop through cpus ?

Comment: yes. about 'b.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Usage)' lambda expression have to return boolean something like 'x => x.Usage == anyval' or use it without lamda

Comment: Still no luck, I get the same error -cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'bool' at b.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Usage)

Comment: because 'x.Usage' is double and not bool. you need boolean expression in lambda expression in brackets  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx

Comment: @demo_user: I guess `b.FirstOrDefault().Usage` is what you want?

Comment: I tried the following too -  Usage = b.FirstOrDefault().Usage

Comment: try var cpus = (from a in db.UsageCPUs
                      where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
                      group a by a.ServerID into b
                      orderby b.Key
                      select new { ServerID = b.Key, 
                      Usage = b.FirstOrDefault() }).ToList(); and then 'foreach(var x in cpus ){ x.ServerID; x.Usage}'

Comment: This doesnt now work - 'foreach(var x in cpus ){ x.ServerID; x.Usage}'  :(