# How to cast an dataitem of anonymous type to a class made of its same types

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

How do you cast a dataitem from a gridview bound to an anonymous type into a class made of the same types? I keep getting an InvalidCastException

This happens in the RowDataBound, using

```
var row = (StationRow)e.Row.DataItem;
```

Against the class:

```
class StationRow
{
    public int StationID { get; set; }
    public string Has_Had_Allocation { get; set; }
    public string Inactive { get; set; }
    public int Block { get; set; }
    public int Session { get; set; }
    public int Rotation { get; set; }
    public int StationNumber { get; set; }
    public string Remove_Station { get; set; }
}
```

The (formatted) error is:

```
{"Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType24`8
[System.Int32,
System.String,
System.String,
System.Int32,
System.Int32,
System.Int32,
System.Int32,
System.String]' to type 'StationRow'."}
```

I figure I could build a datatable and pump the linq result into that, then bind to the table, making it a DataRowView but that seems inefficient, so i'd appreciate if anyone can point out what i'm missing.

Comment: How is the datatable bound? Why doesn't the ling project to `StationRow` items rather than an anonymous type?

Comment: You can't just implicitly convert anonimous type to some known type. You'll need either [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24257939/1021555), [explicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275899/1021555) or some other way. Or just use StationRow instead of the anon type to begin with.

Comment: To answer the question, there's not a way to cast to a different type just because the property names line up.

Comment: Why do you create anonymous type objects and not `StationRow` objects directly?

Comment: @GertArnold if you put that into an answer, i'll mark it as correct

Comment: It's just a question. And @icebat also suggested it.

Comment: @icebat The answer to the question is that originally there wasn't a class, I made it for a different problem, and didn't think to take it back up to the original query. Regardless, if someone makes an answer out of it, i'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

This answer is entirely not recommended, and the suggestions in the comments to return the correct class from the query are a much better idea.

With some extension methods on `MemberInfo` to generalize handling of properties or fields:

```
// ***
// *** Type Extensions
// ***
public static MemberInfo[] GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
    t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field | mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToArray();

public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}

public static void SetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, T value) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            mfi.SetValue(destObject, value);
            break;
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            mpi.SetValue(destObject, value);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}
```

you can write an extension method that copies the properties or field values to the (name) matching properties or fields in another object:

```
public static T ToType<T>(this object item) where T : new() {
    var ansObj = new T();
    var ansType = typeof(T);

    foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetPropertiesOrFields()) {
            var destField = ansType.GetMember(prop.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Single();
            destField.SetValue(ansObj, prop.GetValue(item));
    }

    return ansObj;
}
```

Now you can create a new object and copy the values:

```
var row = e.Row.DataItem.ToType<StationRow>();
```